# I keep getting an error when trying to start Apache2 on my Ubuntu server 16.04.1

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, php-7

This has something to do with **php7.0** and I believe I've installed everything necessary but it still won't run. I get:

`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

and when I check the apache2.service I see

> apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib

I swear I've installed **libapache2-mod-php7.0** but nothing seems to make a difference. As soon as I disable it with `sudo a2dismod php7` it works fine.

I think I've exhausted all I know. Please help!

Comment: Tried to remove and reinstall `apache`? seems something broken in apache config

Comment: Can you share the output of `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/`? make sure here `php7.0.load` and `php7.0.conf` these files exist.

Comment: Post the Content of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Hi all, I am facing the same problem @SahilGulati I have listed all mods-available and php.7.0.load/conf is available

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on my original post... way after the fact. I ended up basically bricking my server that day. It would start to boot then error too many ways to count. So I cut my losses and reinstalled Ubuntu. Now my apache server works properly (with php). Probably not that helpful, but just thought I'd weigh in.